# Replacing NaN values in a column from a second column

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to replace `NaN` values in `Target` with the corresponding `Node` value.
My data is:

```
 Node  Target   Color
node1   node7   Red
node1   node9   Red
node3   node5   Green
node1   node3   Red
node3   node1   Red
node5   NaN     Yellow
```

I would need to have:

```
   Node  Target     Color
    node1   node7   Red
    node1   node9   Red
    node3   node5   Green
    node1   node3   Red
    node3   node1   Red
    node5   node5   Yellow # here the replacement
```

I think that a possible solution could be using an if statement to check if a node has `Target` equal to NaN: if yes, then it would be possible to assign itself as target.

Comment: `df["Target"] = df["Target"].fillna(df["Node"])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [**`df.fillna(value, ...)`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) will allow the **`value` (replacement) arg to be a Series (column)**, not just a constant:

```
df['Target'] = df['Target'].fillna(df['Node'])
```

Note this is better than if...else logic because it does one vectorized assignment to the entire dataframe, as the testcase below shows.

---

2. Alternative, if `df.fillna()` hadn't allowed us to do this:

You could also use [`df.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) on your column of interest, where the **`df.where(... other)`** arg is your replacement column, `df['Node']`:

```
df['Target'] = df['Target'].where(df['Target'].notna(), df['Node'])
```

Note also how we use logical indexing, using `df['Target'].notna()` to get us a mask/ logical vector of rows where Target is/isn't NA.

Better testcase:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = """ Node  Target   Color
node1   node7   Red
node1   node9   Red
node2   NaN     Brown
node3   node5   Green
node1   node3   Red
node3   node1   Red
node5   NaN     Yellow"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df), sep=r'\s+')
```